# Swift - change action event to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

i'm trying to change the default action when user press on a text field. I tried to connect my action at `Editing Did Begin` event using storyboard as you can see below. The problem is that the keyboard always appear but I want that the keyboard doesn't never appear.

I cannot delete text field delegate methods cause i have others text field in the same view.

How can i do?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Try this for single textfield keyboard never show

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == yourTextField
    {
        textField.inputView = UIView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your view controller as your textField delegate and implement UITextField textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate method.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == yourTextField {
        // implement custom behaviour
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if(textField == YourtextField){
       return false
      }
    return true
  }
```

OR:

in your `viewDidLoad()` set  `yourTextField.inputView = UIView()`

Works in both ways. Use suitable one.